# How to put in "value" argument of VLOOKUP function the whole column?

Tags: excel-formula

I have two tables. First table has two columns: `ID` and `Name`. And in the first table are all IDs and names.

Second table also has two columns: `ID` and `Name`. But this table does not contain all IDs and names.

I want to do this: when I enter an ID in the second table in column `ID`, I want to automatically pick up the name from the first table of that ID and print it in column `Name` on the second table.

Also, I know to do this for just one row. For example:

`=VLOOKUP($B1; TABLE1!A:B; 2; FALSE)`

But I want to do this for whole column `ID` in the second table.

How can I do this?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but can you just copy the `VLOOKUP` formula you describe from one cell and paste it to all cells in the table 2 `Name` column?

Answer (score 0):

You can use vlookup formula with Array..however in any case you have to paste the formula in next cell in order to get it worked.